# Passing a class variable from Models.py to another .py file for processing

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-imaging-library

Note: I am a django/python beginner

I currently have a User class in models.py that allows a user to upload an image to my app. This is supported by a form and template that allow the upload. This part is working fine. The issue is that I am receiving the image in the filefield within the model, but i need to get this image into my EnhanceImage.py file. Once there, I can process it with the code in this script to create an enhanced version with Pillow.

How should I set this up differently than what I am doing now? The goal in my mind is to get the image variable from the User class into the EnhanceImage.py file to be used for enhancement. I want to get it into the UserUploadedImage variable in the EnhanceImage.py file

I've tried just about every solution i can find online to pass the variable to the new file.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from stdimage.models import StdImageField


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='something')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to='images/', variations={'thumbnail': {'width': 640, 'height': 480}}, default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

ImageEnhance.py

The goal of this file is to take the UserUploadedImage and overlay content using pillow.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFont, ImageDraw

UserUploadedImage = I need the user uploaded image here!

foreground = Image.open("path/to/Image_to_overlay.jpg")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(UserUploadedImage)

draw.rectangle([(-11, 420), (640, 515)], fill=(255,255,255), outline=(0,0,0))

UserUploadedImage.paste(foreground, (300, 385), foreground)
...
#more code below that isn't important for my question
```

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'content', 'image']
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import User
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView # new
from django.urls import reverse_lazy #new
from .forms import UserForm # new


def home(request):
    context = {
        'users': User.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)


class CreateUploadView(CreateView): # new
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'main/photoupload.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Comment: Can you show us your forms.py as well as views.py ?

Comment: Your first mistake is thinking in terms of files, in any case. You should think in terms of functions. The code in ImageEnhance.py *must* be in a function, and you need to call that function from somewhere and pass the path. But as JPG says, we need the form and view to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just added in the Forms.py and Views.py file for your review.

Comment: I have this issue also: It is unintuitive as to how one can pass the media url to view.py (or ImageEnhance.py in this case) for manipulation/processing.